# apache web server rewrites paths removing domain part ( /path instead of http://IPaddress:port/path)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, window.location

I have a couple of angularjs projects which I serve over apache web server.
They are all under different folders in same level so I just wanted to use apache web server. I navigate between projects with a combobox and a button. Selection then matched with a key value pair from a json array. value is just the path to the selected project's index.html

However, sometimes (randomly) it navigates to 
project2/dist/index.html instead of:
http://10.0.1.27:8090/project2/dist/index.html

and I receive DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN or ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on browser (chrome)

When I give full URL instead of path then randomly something else happens: It sometimes tries to go to (attention colon ':' after http)
http//10.0.1.27:8090/project2/dist/index.html

Edit: Navigation Part:

html Side

```
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              Report
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <select  style="width:150px" id="urlListCombobox">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in urlList" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="float: right;margin-right: 30px;">
            <button  type="button"  style="min-width: 100px;"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right" ng-click="redirectUrl()">Get Report</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Javascript side

```
$scope.urlList = {
  "/project1/dist/index.html" : "Project 1",
  "/project2/dist/index.html" : "Project 2",
  "/project3/dist/index.html" : "Project 3",
  "/project4/dist/index.html" : "Project 4",
  "/project5/dist/index.html" : "Project 5"
};

$scope.redirectUrl= function(){
  var url = $("#urlListCombobox").val();
  if(url != 0){
    window.location=url;
  }
}
```

Any idea why this can happen?
Any comments appreciated.

Recently I needed "Rewrite on" with an .htaccess file. After this I review an increase of occurrences. I also updated httpd.conf file from

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    # Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Is the problem about rewrites? Does anyone know about such a bug of apache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Randomly huh?  Maybe cosmic rays are hitting your client pc causing it to mutate strings?  In seriousness, you should edit your question to show us your html and js code to start, and possibly .htaccess.

Comment: Haha! :D... Honestly now I am reading what an .htaccesss file is. I will also update my question after reading some about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was the result of pure inattention, not anything related to apache :)

One change of mine two months ago led to a duplicate function.

```
$scope.redirectUrl= function(){
      var url = $("#urlListCombobox").val();
      if(url != 0){
        window.location=url;
      }
    }
```

The duplicate function below was selected by browser (for which reason I don't know) randomly.

```
$scope.redirectUrl= function(){
      var url = $("#urlListCombobox").val();
      if(url != 0){
        location.replace("http://" + url)
      }
    }
```

Deleting the duplicate fixed the issue.